# Let's check that domain port

Tags: python, performance, python-2.x, socket, status-monitoring

#### Intro

This simple script will allow me to check for a specific opened port on a list of domains that I own. Instead of manually doing this check, I found Python a pretty good idea for such a task.

After profiling my code, I found out that `def check_for_open_ports():` is really slow. It takes about **0:01:16.799242 seconds** for 4 domains.

I wondered if there's a good / recommended way of improving this (maybe multithreading / multiprocessing). While asking for an answer which implements one of the above two methods is forbidden here, I wouldn't mind seeing one. I know that one shall use multiprocessing when there're I/O bound tasks which makes me believe I might go with a multithreading solution.

---

#### The code

```
from socket import gethostbyname, gaierror, error, socket, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM
from sys import argv, exit
import re

DOMAINS_FILE = argv[1]
PORT = argv[2]
OUTPUT_FILE = argv[3]


def get_domains():
    """
    Return a list of domains from domains.txt
    """
    domains = []
    if len(argv) != 4:
        exit("Wrong number of arguments\n")
    try:
        with open(DOMAINS_FILE) as domains_file:
            for line in domains_file:
                domains.append(line.rstrip())
    except IOError:
        exit("First argument should be a file containing domains")
    return domains


def check_domain_format(domain):
    """
    This function removes the beginning of a domain if it starts with:

    www.
    http://
    http://www.
    https://
    https://www.
    """
    clear_domain = re.match(r"(https?://(?:www\.)?|www\.)(.*)", domain)
    if clear_domain:
        return clear_domain.group(2)
    return domain


def transform_domains_to_ips():
    """
    Return a list of ips specific to the domains in domains.txt
    """
    domains = get_domains()
    domains_ip = []
    for each_domain in domains:
        each_domain = check_domain_format(each_domain)
        try:
            domains_ip.append(gethostbyname(each_domain))
        except gaierror:
            print("Domain {} not ok. Skipping...\n".format(each_domain))
    return domains_ip


def check_for_open_ports():
    """
    Check for a specific opened PORT on all the domains from domains.txt
    """
    ips = transform_domains_to_ips()
    try:
        with open(OUTPUT_FILE, 'a') as output_file:
            for each_ip in ips:
                try:
                    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
                    result = sock.connect_ex((each_ip, int(PORT)))

                    if result == 0:
                        output_file.write(each_ip + '\n')
                    sock.close()
                except error:
                    print("Couldn't connect to server")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit("You pressed CTRL + C. Will exit now...\n")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    check_for_open_ports()
```

---

#### A step further

After some checks, I realised that what was *mainly* slowing down the program can be improved by reducing the default timeout from the `socket` module using `setdefaulttimeout(2)`.

Even if this solved a part of the problem, I still don't find it to be the cleanest one. Any advice related to performance is really welcome !

---

#### Extra info:

- I'll probably use this only on Linux OSs
- I've used Python 2.7.13

PS: *I'd like you to ignore the fact that I didn't use `optparse` or `argparse` for parsing CLI arguments.*

Comment: My question was firstly [asked on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41980859/use-of-socket-module-multithreading-or-multiprocessing), but I had a second thought and as [discussed on chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35151599#35151599), I _came back home on CR_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First a slight style note (IMHO, of course). You called your function `check_domain_format`, but it's actually returning a modified string and you're using the result, not checking it. I'd go for a name like `validate_domain_format`

About it being slow:

- Yes, multi-threading would help in checking multiple domains at once, but if that was the only problem you could just make a separate bash script to launch your python script with different parameters.
- You said that you own the domains, so I'm assuming you have `RAW` socket capabilities. If that's the case, you can speed up your check by using a `SYN` check. You can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39024816/how-to-create-a-port-scanner-tcp-syn-using-the-method-tcp-syn) , even if the question has been down-voted, it should give you the general idea. [Here](http://www.arti-sec.com/article/spse-module-2-lesson-4-syn-scanner-python) you can find that same check.
- If you're doing this for educational purposes that's ok, otherwise `nmap` will most likely do a better job, give you more options and be faster (because `SYN` check is already implemented and you can also scan for UDP ports, for example).